# show a html block every page except one specific page in row php

Tags: php, html, yii

I have a html block which i want to show every pages except the login page.

In my project folder I have these files. 
index.php 
services.php 
about.php

------ 
------ 
contact.php 
login.php

I have common header which i include via php. In my header I want to show a html block every pages except the login.php page.

In that case I declare a veriable in login.php page
 // Login.php

```
<?php

$loginPage = "hide";

?>
```

Header Section

```
<?php if (!($loginPage == "hide" )): ?> 
<a class="btn btn-secondary signin" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/store/login">Sign in <span class="highlighter"></span></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In common header I have write this code for not showing this block in login.php page. But its not working what's going wrong with this ? 
 
One more thing that I will implement this logic into yii framework. To understand the logic I use raw php.

Comment: Is that html block inside a menu? Have you tried to use a widget?

Comment: No this is just an a tag like this

<a class="btn btn-secondary signin" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/store/login">Sign in <span class="highlighter"></span></a>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if ($loginPage != "hide" ) { ?> 
<a class="btn btn-secondary signin" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/store/login">Sign in <span class="highlighter"></span></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change your if condition to the following:

```
if ( $loginPage != "hide" ):
```

Although you should consider using a boolean like

```
$showLogin = true;
```

instead of using a string ;)